# How to use data from useActionData or useLoaderData in ActionFunction

Tags: reactjs, remix, remix.run

I have a loader function that in this example and in my case gets a **client object** and I have it in useLoaderData().

I also have a form made with **fetcher.Form** and after I submit it I need that **client object** in my action function. How do I get it to use it there ?

This is my loader function:

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
    let client: string | mqtt.MqttClient | null = null;
    let error = null;
    let connected = false;
    try {
        client = await mqttConnect('172.31.100.181', options)
        client = stringify(client);
        connected = true;
    }
    catch (e: any) {
        error = `Client connect error: ${e.message}`;
        console.log('Client connect error: ', e.message)
    }

    return json({
        client,
        error,
        connected
    });
}
```

And the following form is:

```
<fetcher.Form>
    <button
        type='button'
        name='_action'
        value='publish_all'
        onClick={() => {
            fetcher.submit({ client: stringify(client), '_action': 'publish_iotbso/feeds/test' }, { method: "post", action: "/mqtt" });
        }}
    >
        All devices
    </button>
    <button type='submit' name='_action' value='publish_bedroom'>Bedroom devices</button>
</fetcher.Form>
```

I found this way of doing it, instead of using the form submit I just put an onClick event on the button and used fetcher.submit with the client object, but I don't think it's the right way and if it will work in all cases. What would be a better way to have that **client** variable in the action function ?

Also, how do I make it so whenever I submit the form bellow, it will not trigger the loader function again ? Because now everytime I press that button with **value='publish_all'**  that sends a fetcher.submit, my loader function is called

Answer (score 0):

Using a fetcher isn't a wrong way of doing this. But you don't need a fetcher for this usecase.

I can think of a 2 other ways to put in client side data into your form. Both methods will send your data to your ActionFunction normally, and you can handle it as you normally would.

You can have an hidden input and a state. Now even with a normal form submit, you will be able to sent whatever data you want to your action function.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

...

<input type="hidden" value={JSON.stringify(data)}/>
```

Another way to do this is with a submitter hook.

```
const submit = useSubmit();

...

<button onClick{() => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("name", JSON.stringify(someComplexJSONObject));
  submit(formData, { method: "POST" });
}} />
```

As for preventing your loader from fetching new data on submits/fetcher actions, though I have not personally used it (havent needed it yet). Remix offers the [shouldRevalidate](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/should-revalidate) function to control when the loader should be invoked.